# Ensure Autocloseable is closed in Cucumber step definitions

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, autocloseable

My Cucumber Java step definitions can create [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) objects, which can acquire external (perhaps scarce) resources. Those objects should have their `close()` method called when they are no longer needed, to free those resources. How do I ensure that the `close()` methods are called?

In a non-Cucumber test, I'd use [try-with-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/try-with-resources). But that is not possible because there is no single method that spans the execution of a scenario (an `AutoCloseable` object might be created in a *when* method, and used in a later *then*).

Comment: I am answering my own question [as is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a method annotated with `io.cucumber.java.After` to callthe `close()` method(s). It's not great; we have to rely on Cucmber, rather than Java itelf, doing the right thing.